# Swift - Hide/Show 'tableHeaderView' on page scroll

Tags: swift, tableheader

I have a button in **tableHeaderView** of a **tableView**. I want to add an effect like the facebook search bar that hides / shows the button on page scroll. It should behave as follows:

1. When page loads, button shows
2. When user scrolls down, button is hidden
3. When user scrolls up slightly, button will appear again

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site to get help for your programming enquiries, not to get others to do them for you.

Comment: I don't expect others to code for me.  I just want a bit of guidance as I am new to IOS @WesleyPeeters

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIScrollViewDelegate` to detect when the user is Scrolling.

Have a look at the Apple Documentation you'll find the article right  [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate)

I hope it helps you.